# ie11 react development, 0.chunk.js code line stops at line 22993

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, internet-explorer-11, create-react-app

I am developing a  react app. (using cra) 
and when testing it in development mode on ie11, I receive random errors (1002,1003,1006 etc...) in the 0.chunk.js file.
when downloading the js file from ie11, I can see that the code breaks ast line 22993.
If I download the js file from chrome, the file is as expected. (with 65072 lines of code)

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe provide at least the errors?

Comment: the errors don't always repeat themselves, eg.SCRIPT1009: Expected ')',
and when following the error to the point in the code I can see that the code ends at that point. (missing over 20 thousand lines)

Comment: Without checking the code we are not able to find the root cause for the issue. as you said file is not getting downloaded completely. so try to check using developer tools that what status code it shows for that JS file. check whether you got any error when file get load completely. If file get load incompletely than it may cause this kind of error.